# Appending link to img jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I'm trying to append a link around an image in `jQuery`. This is the current code so far:

```
showPins: function(options) {

        var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

        this.css({'cursor' : options.cursor, 'background-color' : options.backgroundColor , 'background-image' : "url('"+options.backgroundImage+"')",'height' : options.fixedHeight , 'width' : options.fixedWidth});

        for(var i=0; i < (options.pinDataSet).markers.length; i++)
        {
            var dataPin = options.pinDataSet.markers[i];

            var imgC = $('<img rel="/map-content.php?id='+dataPin.id+'" class="pin '+options.pinclass+'" style="top:'+dataPin.ycoord+'px;left:'+dataPin.xcoord+'px;">');
            imgC.attr('src',  options.pin);
            imgC.attr('title',  dataPin.title);

            var a = $('<a>', {href:options.pinurl}).appendTo(imgC);

            imgC.appendTo(this);
        }
    }
```

Instead I'm receiving this

[image: this]

I'm not sure how to wrap the href around the  tag. Instead the img tag is wrapping around the href.

Comment: jQuery wrap will do it. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to switch the elements around in your code. `$(element).appendTo(element2)` appends `element` to the inside of `element2`., so in your case, the problem is that

```
var a = $('<a>', {href:options.pinurl}).appendTo(imgC);
```

should be

```
var a = $('<a>', {href:options.pinurl});
imgC.appendTo(a);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.append` instead of `.appendTo`.

From http://api.jquery.com/append/ :

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major
>   difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the
>   content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding
>   the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With
>   .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and
>   it is inserted into the target container.